# Use FILTER function and checkbox together in EXCEL

Tags: excel

I have a table in DATA sheet in C1:E100.
I create a list of unique data of E in O1:O10.
How to use FILTER function to show C and D based on FALSE or TRUE that I write in front of O1:O10 (column P)?

I wrote this function but it doesn't work:

```
FILTER(DATA!C:D,IF(P:P,DATA!E:E=O:O,""))
```

Answer (score 0):

=FILTER(DATA!C:D, ISNUMBER(MATCH(DATA!E:E, $O$1:$O$10, 0)))

Here's what each part of the formula does:

DATA!C:D: The data range you want to filter.
DATA!E:E: The column of values you want to check against your list in O1:O10.
$O$1:$O$10: The range of cells containing the unique data in column E.
MATCH(DATA!E:E, $O$1:$O$10, 0): This part checks for matches between the values in column E and the unique values in O1:O10. The MATCH function returns the relative position of an item in a range. The 0 as the third argument indicates an exact match.
ISNUMBER(MATCH(...)): This part converts the result of the MATCH function into a TRUE/FALSE value. If there's a match, MATCH returns a number, and ISNUMBER returns TRUE; otherwise, it returns FALSE.
FILTER(DATA!C:D, ISNUMBER(MATCH(...))): This part uses the FILTER function to filter the data in columns C:D based on the TRUE/FALSE values obtained from the MATCH function.